# compare databases (tables only) using C# and Ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I am trying to develop a software that takes two databases as its input, compares there tables and show differences between tables.

This is what I think and develop.

1) Select all the servers that are installed on machine.
2) Depending on the selected server it list all the databases installed.
3)  Depending upon the Databases, this method returns all the tables names in the database.
4)  Now I have info about two databases and name of all the tables in both the databases. I am filling both the databases into two DataSet objects (source, destination).
5)  Now, I am iterating both DataSet, comparing each tables (corresponding to index). And keeping record of the index on which two datatables are not same.

My problem is-
1) take two databases as its input.
2) show the differences (on table data) in GUI. And update both source and/or destination databases.

Difference: 
Show/Highlight all the table records that are present in sourceDB but not in destinationDB and user must have ability to select these records individually then application should insert these records into destinationDB.

Show/highlight all the table records that are present in destinationDb but not in sourceDb and user must have ability to select these records individually and delete them from destination.

Can I do the same thing using Entity Framework?

Comment: you simply CAN'T do the same with entity framework, since EF maps all entries of the ResultSet to the corresponding type. Even if you used an anonymous type, you wouldn't be able to get the table schema with this. The only possibility would be with plain SQL querying the metadata, and for this you can use ado.net more efficiently.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro thanks for reply. I have stored the databases into two DataSet object, now could you guide me how to display them in windows form and show the differences (on table data) in GUI. And update both source and/or destination databases.

Difference: Show/Highlight all the table records that are present in sourceDB but not in destinationDB and user must have ability to select these records individually then application should insert these records into destinationDB.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the point in doing all this in your application code. This rightly looks like a DB responsibility and would be best if you offload it there. I mean, you should write a SQL query for doing all this and get the data and then you can display that data in your application.

Here is one sample [SQL Server : Script to Find and Create Missing Tables for Database Sychronization](http://www.connectsql.com/2013/11/sql-server-script-to-find-and-create.html)

Comment: this doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

"Right" use of entity framework is to work on a known model and in your case you are not.
ADO.Net is the right choice.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have stored the databases into two DataSet object, now could you guide me how to display them in windows form and show the differences (on table data) in GUI. And update both source and/or destination databases. Difference: Show/Highlight all the table records that are present in sourceDB but not in destinationDB and user must have ability to select these records individually then application should insert these records into destinationDB.